# Listen to mqtt messages for x minutes

Tags: c#, .net, events, mqtt

At the moment I'm trying to develop something that will listen to mqtt messages for x minutes. One of the problems I have and have asked in this forum is that I do a while for x minutes. But I think this may not be a good approach.

I have subscribed to an event like this:

```
private void MqttBroker_MqttMessagePublishedReceived(object sender, Events.MqttMessageEventArgs e)
{
    _logger?.Information($"MqttBroker_MqttMessagePublishedReceived - message received by the watcher {e}");
    try
    {
        if (e?.Payload != null)
        {
            _messages.AddMessage(e.Payload);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger?.Error($"MqttBroker_MqttMessagePublishedReceived - Something went wrong: {ex}");
    }
}
```

But in my main program (a console application) I subscribe to the topic, I start the recording. Basically just init a new list to add messages to. After that I publish my message and in the next method I just perform a while loop for x minutes. I don't like this approach and I'm looking for something better. With a `thread.sleep` I'm afraid that it will completely block my events getting raised. So I was thinking of a timer but I think it is the same as my while loop eventually.

```
broker.Connect();
broker.Subscribe("config/#");
mqttWatcher.StartRecording(4);
topicHandler.Execute("topic", "json");   // does the publish
var messages= mqttWatcher.StopRecording();
broker.Close();
```

At the moment my stop recording is nothing more then just a while loop:

```
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        while (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_maxTimeoutInMinutes))
        {
        }
```

How can I consume these events for x minutes?

Comment: What kind of application is your main program? A console application? A service? Or a GUI application?

Comment: Just a console application

Comment: Use a Timer with a small interval (circa 100 ms) to check elapsed time, use code similar to the one you use in the while loop. Just store the startTime before starting the timer.